# iOS Blocks - defining UIView animation-like blocks

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to create a custom block like the `UIView` animation blocks. Basically I want to be able to pass either a method or any number of instructions and also provide a completion handler. My question is how would I specify the arguments part of the block definition?

Comment: See [Blocks Programming Topcis](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH1-SW1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a method declaration such as:

```
- (void) performAnimationWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion {

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            // your own animation code 
            // ...
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                // your own completion code

                // if completion block defined, call it
                if(completion){
                    completion(YES);
                }
            }];

}
```

Then, you can call it with:

```
[instance performAnimationWithCompletion:^(BOOL complete){
      // define block code to be executed on completion
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         // other animations here

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         // ... completion stuff
                     }
     ];
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I replicate the  animations:^ part in the declaration?